# What is an acceptable loss with external networks?

Tags: internet, packet-loss

Based on my reading here, any traffic loss on the internal network should be quickly addressed. However what is an acceptable level of loss one can expect when communicating with external networks? Some IPs are showing ~30% with a surprisingly large group in the 5-15% range. Obviously the former is undesirable. What's considered acceptable?

#### Edit

The scenario is small to medium enterprise network. No VoIP or gaming. Casual personal browsing including video and music streaming. Heavy reliance on cloud services such as AWS, Azure, etc and Video conferencing. Most of the loss isn't associated with business critical applications; instead tertiary level and beyond.

I understand how this can be considered opinion based since there are so many variables. I would really like some ballpark to gauge what an acceptable level of loss is.

Would a better question be: How much traffic loss occurs before a route is flagged degraded/down and a new route is used?

Comment: There is no agreed upon number.  It can depend on many factors.  Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: What are the requirements of your users and applications?  VOIP and gaming are the first common home/office apps to suffer when you introduce some packet loss, even a small amount.  Many other common applications will work just fine with 5% loss, maybe without users even noticing.

Comment: While this is highly debatable, a serious network has an acceptable loss rate of far below 1%. My limit is 10 ppm (0.001%). Completely different scenario if you talk about WAN though.

Comment: Another useful point of information may be carrier SLAs.  A typical SLA for IP transit is 99% packet delivery (or <= 1% loss) on the carrier's in-region network (e.g. US+Canada or Europe) and many offer 99.9%.  Promises are generally lower for trans-Atlantic/Pacific traffic.  They all exceed these SLA benchmarks almost all the time.  It's fair to say .1% loss is commercially unacceptable for common use over any extended period of time.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. They've been very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any hard wired network, there should normally be zero loss. Saturating a link and overloading any buffers aside, networking technology is very reliable.

However, if there are RF links in the path -- wifi, microwave, satellite -- then from time to time, some amount of loss will be unavoidable; you're at the mercy of real world interference. How much loss is acceptable is up to the user, and possibly their contract(s).

Answer (score 0):

> Would a better question be: How much traffic loss occurs before a route is flagged degraded/down and a new route is used?

This depends on the routing protocol.  The most common protocols, OSPF, EIGRP and BGP exchange "keep alive" packets (also called "hello" packets), to let their neighbors know they're still there.  Typically, if a router loses 3 keep-alives in a row, the neighbor is declared dead and the routes from the neighbor are removed.  Depending on the protocol, the keepalives are sent anywhere from every second (sometimes even faster) to 30 seconds.

This implies that the quality of a link can quite poor -- even 50% loss will allow some keepalives to get through -- before a router will remove a neighbor.

Since routers only operate at layer 3, they can't tell if packets are getting lost.  Only the end hosts can tell that.

Some routers can send probe packets to measure link performance and adjust routing accordingly.  There is no standard for this, and every manufacturer does it differently.  Cisco's feature is called IP SLA, and others have different names.

Comment: Routing protocol traffic is not typically affected by congestion due to the presence of (and default configuration) QoS/CoS features on most modern routers.  Packets for OSPF, BGP, etc. are classified as `network-control` and will not contend with best-effort user traffic.  This is why you can have a huge amount of packet loss and not see flapping.  It's a good thing, because that kind of flapping could lead to oscillation, rather than switching to a "better" path.

Comment: Network congestion is not the only factor.  There are other sources of loss.  I felt the OP was asking about how routes are removed when  loss occurs..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I was trying to say is if significant loss is observed, what is the threshold to declare the route degraded and choose an alternative?

Comment: @user2320464 As I tried to explain, routers don't do that.  They don't measure loss or anything similar. 
 They can only determine that their routing neighbor is unreachable.  If, for example, you have high loss to some host on the Internet, all the routers between you and the host will continue to advertise that route to the host until it gets so bad that the routers can't talk to each other.

Comment: The exception is custom features like IP SLA, but not widely used.

Comment: Is there ever a time when routes are modified after observing significant loss via [netflow](https://www.plixer.com/blog/cisco-performance-reporting-on-your-medianet/), [solarwinds](https://www.solarwinds.com/network-bandwidth-analyzer-pack/use-cases/network-traffic-monitor), etc.? What would be that threshold? Suppose it is all "situation based"?

Comment: @user2320464 It can be done in specific cases, but that would be a very custom implementation. So there is no usual threshold.

Comment: The problem with changing routes based on performance is that the conditions are constantly changing. Routers would be continuously calculating routes and everything would be unstable.